# Firebase Custom Event Value is always 0

Tags: unity-game-engine, firebase-analytics

I am hitting firebase custom event through unity and I am not able to get the event value as shown in the image. It is always 0.
[view image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VJ3nY.png)

I tried sending a double value instead of a string as one of the parameters.
I tried adding custom parameters into custom metrics as well (earlier it was inside custom definitions).

I also tried

```
new Parameter(FirebaseAnalytics.ParameterValue, value);
```

still no results.

Any help will be much appreciated.